# Find a discord user just by username (no tag)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, discord, console

like title states I wanna find an old friend of mine, but the only thing I know it's his username, no tag number..
No mutual servers or anything unfortunally, and the discord search feature didn't helped.
So my idea was to send a friend request to all 9999 possible tags with that username.
But doing it manually, well it would take so long, I could try setup a macro, but I would like to know if there's a way I could make a program or discord bot using discord apis to accomplish this faster.
I would just need check the pending friends list in the end and should be done.
Weird nobody did yet such a thing, lots of people would benefit with such a software or whatever it could be.

Answer (score 0):

What this code does is create range from 0 to 9999 and sends friend request to all usernames within range.

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE',
}

data = {
    'username': 'YOUR_FRIEND_USERNAME',
    'discriminator': 0,
}

var link = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/relationships'

for i in range(10000):
    data[discriminator] = i
    r = requests.post(link, headers=headers, json=data).text
    print(str(i) + ":" + str(r))
```

But remember there's legal advice:

- Self bots are illegal in Discord's terms of service.
- You are not allowed to send such no. of friend requests. Off course Discord will restrict/expire/ban your token.